# XHTML Transitional 1.o Highlight single word within unordered ul tag

Tags: list, xhtml, unordered, transitional

I have an unordered list and each item is a sentence. I would like to highlight a word or two within the sentence but the font color tag

```
<font color="CC9966">highlighted words </font>
```

generates an error. Can anyone please suggest a fix for this? I have tried putting it in

```
<li> </li>
```

and while it works and generates no error, but this is not the formatting I want as I have a roll over on the li in my CSS style sheet. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap a span around the word you want to highlight. It would probably be easier to make a class in the CSS called highlight and use that though.

```
<span style="color:#DD0000">wordToHighlight</span>
```

You can check a documents validity by using the [W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check). These are the people that make the rules. If you change the tab to validate by direct input and put in:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
<li>this is a <span style="color:#FF0000">test</span> sentence</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

You will see that **a span in a li is valid markup**.

Comment: Thank you. I tried that and I get the error: The tag span not allowed within "ul". It is only allowed within: a, abr, acronym, ...

Comment: What is generating this error, and what version of HTML are you using?

Comment: The DOC type is XHTML Transitional 1.0. I am using Dreamweaver CS4 and using it's validation. The error occurs when I try to change color of a single word inside a ul tag.

Comment: Thank you. I have made a class called highlight in the CSS stylesheet and am trying to get it to work. However, I am trying to make a font/color change in a ul tag, not an li tag in an unordered list.

Comment: Read the html spec. The only valid child element of a ul is an li. if you don't want it in the list, don't put it in there. Sounds like you might need to go over some of the basics of html. Heres a good place: http://www.w3schools.com/html/

Comment: Thank you. It seems that I am not communicating the issue properly. It appears that I need to create a nested list with the roll over on the nested part.